# Wrong checked checkbox Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, checkbox

I have a problem with a template with AngularJS.
The page shows a books list with a checkbox. This is used for batch actions, like delete the books. If the list is too long, the books will be shown in a paged list

The problem is, if I check some of them and change the page number, the checkbox will be checked in the same position.
Is easier to understan with this screenshots

- I check the first and the third result:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK5jE.jpg
- Click on the next page:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEuMc.jpg

Distinct pages and results, same checked checkbox

The get this results I´m using a query in a action.class.php and sending the json like this:

```
$ejemplares = array();
foreach($data as $ejemplar_bd)
{
    $id_documento = $ejemplar_bd['id_registro'];

    $ejemplar = array();
    $ejemplar['id'] = $ejemplar_bd['id'];
    $ejemplar['idDoc'] = (int)$ejemplar_bd['id_registro'];
    $ejemplar['numregistro'] = (int)$ejemplar_bd['numregistro'];
    $ejemplar['codigo'] = $ejemplar_bd['codigoejemplar'];
    $ejemplar['estado'] = $ejemplar_bd['estado'];
    $ejemplar['signatura'] = $ejemplar_bd['signatura1']."-".$ejemplar_bd['signatura2']."-".$ejemplar_bd['signatura3'];
    $ejemplar['tipo'] =$ejemplar_bd['tipoejemplar'];
    $ejemplar['reservas']=$ejemplar_bd['reservas'];
    $ejemplar['Ubicacion']=$ubicaciones[$ejemplar_bd['id']];
    $ejemplar['Motivo']=$ejemplar_bd['motivo_expurgado'];
    $ejemplar['Editorial']=$data_editorial['valor'];
    $ejemplar['Imprimido']= $ejemplar_bd['imprimido'];
    $ejemplar = array_merge($ejemplar,$fondos[$id_documento][$ejemplar['id']]);

    $ejemplares[] = $ejemplar;

}

$this->json_data = json_encode($ejemplares);
```

After that, the code in the template is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data| filter:Buscar | filtroNumregistro:numregistro | filtroCodEjemplar:codEjemplar | filtroNombreNormalizado:nombreFiltro  | orderBy:sort:reverse | limitTo: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize - filtrados.length | limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
        <td class="sf_admin_text sf_admin_list_td_nombre">
          <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="{{ item.id }}" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text">
          {{ item.codigo }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text">
          {{ item.numregistro }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text sf_admin_list_td_titulo">
            <span><a ng-href="{{cambiarUrlTitulo(item.id)}}">{{ item.Titulo }}</a></span><br/>
            <span class="autorListEjemplar" ng-repeat="autor in item.Autor">{{autor}}{{$last ? '' : ' - '}}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.ISBN }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.Editorial }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.Ubicacion }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text" style="width:10%;">
          {{ item.signatura }}
        </td>
        <td class="sf_admin_text">
          {{ item.tipo }}
        </td>
      </tr> etc...
```

What is going on?
What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have to replace:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="{{ item.id }}" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
```

for

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
```